# C++ finding the positions of regex matches in a string

Tags: c++, regex

I have a few issues with my algorithm, trying to acquire the positions of regex matches in a string.
Please find the code here - https://godbolt.org/z/aj8Gq4Moh

```
std::vector<int> mval;

int closed_val = 0;
int open_val = 0;
std::string da_line = "} } }";
std::smatch m;
std::regex_search(da_line, m, std::regex("([\\}]+)"));
for (auto mv : m) std::cout << mv << std::endl;
std::cout << m.size() << std::endl;
closed_val = da_line.find(m[0]);
mval.push_back(closed_val);
try {
    if (m.size() >= 1) {
        std::string db_line;
        for (int j = 1; j < m.size(); j++) {
            std::cout << da_line << std::endl;
            db_line = da_line.substr(da_line.find(m[j]) + 1, da_line.size() - 1);
            std::cout << db_line << std::endl;
            int f = db_line.find(m[j]);
            if (f == -1 || f > db_line.size() - 1)
                continue;
                std::cout << f << std::endl;
            open_val = closed_val + f + 1;
            for (auto mv : m) std::cout << mv << std::endl;
            std::cout << db_line.find(m[j + 1]) << std::endl;
            mval.push_back(open_val);
            closed_val = open_val;
            da_line = db_line;
        }
    }
}
catch (std::exception& error) {
    std::cerr << "error : " << error.what() << std::endl;
}

for (auto mv : mval) std::cout << mv << ":";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
}
}
2
} } }
 } }
1
}
}
0
0:2:
```

1. Why does the regex return 2 matches when there are 3,
2. The expected result is 0:2:4 when it returns 0:2

Comment: Please [edit] your post and cut and paste the code into here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all the matches in an input, you normally want to use a `regex_iterator` (specifically an `sregex_iterator`, in this case), something on this order:

```cpp
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s = "} } }";

    std::regex pattern("([\\}]+)");
    auto begin = std::sregex_iterator {s.begin(), s.end(), pattern};
    auto end = std::sregex_iterator();

    for (std::sregex_iterator i = begin; i != end; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Found match at position: " << i->position() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Found match at position: 0
Found match at position: 2
Found match at position: 4
```

Comment: Great Example, Thanks for the tip Jerry.

Answer (score 2):

You have a basic misunderstanding of the function `std::regex_search`. It will only search **1** match (or nothing). Please read again [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search).

Also `std::match_results` does work completely differently. But there is a really good explanation in the description of the [std::regex_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search).

Please note:

If a match could be found for your regex, basically for '}', `m.size()` will be 2 and only `m[0]` will be relevant.

`std::match_results` will only contain more then one results, if there are more than 1 sub-matches. For example with a regex "a|b" you could have 2 elements.

---

You need to follow the "Notes" part in the function description.

> In order to examine all matches within the target sequence, std::regex_search may be called in a loop, restarting each time from m[0].second of the previous call. std::regex_iterator offers an easy interface to this iteration.

And, basically, for your specific wish, to find the positions of '}'  in a string, you would not need `std::regex_search` at all. `.find()` in a loop would be completely sufficient.

But I understand that you want to have the more general "regex" approach.

At the moment I do not see a good solution. However, the following will work for your example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    // We want to search in this string
    std::string line{ " abx    aby   abz" };

    // regex for search a }
    const std::regex re{ R"(ab?)" };

    // Here we will store the running position
    std::size_t position{};

    // Search all occurences of regex in the given string
    for (std::smatch sm; std::regex_search(line, sm, re); line = sm.suffix()) {

        // Search the character and add to current position
        position += line.find(sm[0]);

        // Show result
        std::cout << position << ' ';

        // Take length of regex into account
        position += std::string(sm[0]).size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great example! Thanks for the tip Gurnet.